# Wait until fragment has been added to the UI

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

In my app I got to a point where, in landscape mode, I need to attach two fragments. In order to do that, the second fragment needs to wait until the first fragment has been attached (added), before it's being added. The reason for it is that the first fragment needs to execute a function that the second fragment needs. I managed to do that via a thread, but in this case it only waits the amount of time indicated, before attaching the second fragment, and in case the first fragment isn't attached in the time given, the app will crush because the second fragment doesn't have the necessary data.

Any better practices (examples) then the code below (like waiting until the first fragment is attached, and no on a certain time interval) ? :

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainContent, fragment).commit();
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait(1000);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
                if (isLandscape) {
                openSecondFragment(mIndex, R.id.rightConent);
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
```

Much appreciated.

The handler i need to be executed in the first fragment:

```
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
protected void loadAccountList() {

    LoadAccountList loadAccountListThread = new LoadAccountList(new Handler() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case LOAD_SUCCESSFUL_CODE:
                items = (ArrayList<Account>) msg.obj;
                break;
            case LOAD_FAILED_IOEXCEPTION_CODE:
                getActivity().showDialog(ERROR_DIALOG);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    loadAccountListThread.start();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fragments lifecycle works in your favor here. According to the documentation the method onStart() is "Called when the Fragment is visible to the user", so I suggest you do something like this in your first fragment class:

```
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).loadSecondFragment();
}
```

And in your Activity:

```
public void loadSecondFragment() {
    if (isLandscape) {
        openSecondFragment(mIndex, R.id.rightConent);
    }    
}
```

And voilá! Try any of the lifecycle methods and see which one works best for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestions but the result is the same. The second fragment is added too soon, therefore the app crashes because it hasn't the necessary data from the first fragment.

Comment: Just one remark, call `((MainActivity)getActivity()).loadSecondFragment();` after you executed your function. not just randomly in some lifecycle method.

Comment: What @SnyersK says is very important, where do you call that necessary function in your first fragment?

Comment: To be more specific, the first fragment contains a thread that interrogates a server, and I need that information from the server on the second fragment.

Comment: Ok, so just wait till the server response and after that you call `((MainActivity)getActivity()).loadSecondFragment();` and that should do the trick

Comment: Yes, but that's the thing I don't know. The interrogation is done via a handler, and I don't know how to verify when it's done. That's why I figured that if I manage the transactions from the activity, I only need to wait for the first fragment to be added, because when it is added the handler had finished interrogating the server.

Comment: I see, but because you are using a different thread, the fact that your fragment is added doesn't mean the server has responded. That why it didn't work with onStart(). Can you post your handler code?

Comment: OK, I pasted the handler code. What I need is that `items` should get populated and then send it to the second fragment. if it's not populated, It will be send null, and that's why the application crashes. But I don't have the slightest clue how to verify when exactly it gets populated.

Comment: Does it not get populated at this point? `items = (ArrayList<Account>) msg.obj;`

Comment: If the handler has finished the execution, yes, it's getting populated. The problem is that the fragment is attached before the handler terminates the execution, and that what causing the problem.

Comment: So why don't you just add this line after the list being populated? `((MainActivity)getActivity()).loadSecondFragment()`

Comment: Because I haven't thought about it this way. :) It looks like it's working for now. I say for now because there's a navigation Drawer involved in the app, and that's why I wanted to have all the necessary data in the Activity. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: But the question still remains. Is there any way to verify when the handler has terminated it's execution ?

Comment: Unfortunately Android doesn't provide a straight forward way to know that, however there's another class that works in the same way and it does let you know when the work is done. It's called `AsyncTask`. Super easy to implement and lots of documentation and tutorials to help you make your own implementation

Comment: pro/con of onActivityCreated instead of onStart?

Answer (score 2):

You can observe Fragments creation by registering [FragmentLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks)
in [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks,%20boolean)).

Implement callbacks of Your interest such as [onFragmentAttached](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks#onFragmentAttached(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20android.content.Context)), [onFragmentResumed](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks#onFragmentResumed(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)).

Answer (score 0):

onCreateView is called when Fragment is created

```
public static class CustomFragment extends SupportMapFragment{

        public CustomFragment() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            return super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);

        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to access this from the activity somehow. I tried something like: fragment.isAdded() instead of the thread, but in this case it returns null every time.

Comment: you probably want to wait until `onAttach`. Then see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html on how to notifiy the activity that the fragment is ready

Comment: Ok, add a listener in the constructor and call it in onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

first off `@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")` is bad. If you're not carefull with leaks, you're memory is gonna fill up.

My solution (it's a personal preference)

I like to use Otto to pass around messages while still having loose coupling.
It allows you to set-up an EventBus to which different classes can simply register and receive the events they want.
In this case, you could make a helper class which loads the data and fires an event when it has received the data (or an error).
Then you catch this in your second fragment and populate your list.
(in the meantime you can show an indefinite progressbar or something)

This way, you don't have to wait for the data to be received before you load your fragment.

You can find the documentation here: https://github.com/square/otto