# My xamarin android app crashes on restart. Using fragments with navigation drawer layout

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin and Android programming and am struggling with an exception.

My app uses the navigation drawer layout and fragments.

It has a data file stored on the android device that contains profiles to load. These are built into a URL for use in a webview control on a fragment.

When the app is run for the first time it asks for permission to access external storage (I am using the plugin.permissions package for this). The app waits for permission and then opens the file and gets the profile selected as default. It then runs a procedure (which takes the profile as a parameter) and this creates the fragment in the main layout. There will be a method called from the fragment class which is why I create an object rather than doing it in the SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction line.

There is a check to see if the profile parameter was null. If it was not then I call the fragment method. _permissionsGranted is passed so that an error message can be displayed on the webview if the app did not have permission to access to file.

**This all works fine when the app is first installed and waits to be granted permissions. After that restarts, bringing up the recents list and going back to the app all cause it to crash.**

I am getting this error:

> Time  Device Name Type    PID Tag Message 01-02 10:54:14.003  Samsung
>   SM-G930F  Info    15603   MonoDroid   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.   at
>   WebRDT2.Fragment_Classes.WebViewFragment.OpenURL
>   (WebRDT2.Classes.EnviromentProfile _environment, System.Boolean
>   _permissionsGranted) [0x00014] in C:\Users\eversonm\source\repos\WebRDT2\WebRDT2\Fragment
>   Classes\WebViewFragment.cs:85    at WebRDT2.MainActivity.LoadProfile
>   (WebRDT2.Classes.EnviromentProfile _ep) [0x00081] in
>   C:\Users\eversonm\source\repos\WebRDT2\WebRDT2\MainActivity.cs:236
>   at WebRDT2.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle
>   savedInstanceState) [0x002fd] in
>   C:\Users\eversonm\source\repos\WebRDT2\WebRDT2\MainActivity.cs:121
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_0
>   (System.Object state) [0x00000] in
>   <6de48997d0c0445dbea8d4d83492d8c6>:0    at
>   Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0 () [0x00000]
>   in <11a340ccc8de43f09c97400139266ef5>:0    at
>   Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in
>   <11a340ccc8de43f09c97400139266ef5>:0    at
>   Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr
>   native__this) [0x00009] in <11a340ccc8de43f09c97400139266ef5>:0    at
>   (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.22(intptr,intptr)

This is referring to the webview object wv. I know this because I've taken then code that uses wv out of this method and the app does not crash. It just calls the method and only clears the cookies.

I have read through the [fragment lifecycle documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle)

but I cannot understand what the issue is. Again, I'm new to this.

MainActivity.cs (work in progress so not asking for hints, just if there's some way I should recode for the webview fragment)

```
namespace WebRDT2
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    {
        List<EnviromentProfile> envList;

        Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.PermissionStatus permissionStatus;
        Bundle mainSavedInstanceState;

        protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            //Set current activity for permissions
            Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;

            //Ask for permissions if we need them
            await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage);


            // Check if permissions were granted
            permissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions.Permission.Storage);


            mainSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;

            // If we received a list of profiles then load else report issue to user
            if (envList != null)
            {
                EnviromentProfile ep = null;

                if (mainSavedInstanceState == null)
                {
                    //Then the application is being loaded for the first time
                    LoadProfile(ep);
                }

            }
        }

        private void LoadProfile(EnviromentProfile _ep)
        {
            Fragment_Classes.WebViewFragment wvf = new Fragment_Classes.WebViewFragment();

            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, wvf)
                .Commit();

            SupportFragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();

            if (_ep != null)
            {
                wvf.OpenURL(_ep, true);
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "_ep is not null", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }


        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            //base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

WebViewFragment.cs

```
namespace WebRDT2.Fragment_Classes
{
    class WebViewFragment : Fragment
    {
        private View view;

        WebView wv;


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.webview, container, false);

            return view;
        }

        public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            wv = view.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
        }


        public override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();

            wv = view.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
        }


        public override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            wv = view.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
        }


        public void OpenURL(EnviromentProfile _environment, bool _permissionsGranted)
        {
            //WebView wv = view.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);

            var cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
            cookieManager.RemoveAllCookie(); // Clear cache

            string myURL = ""; // URL to load

            wv.SetWebViewClient(new XPOWebViewClient());
            wv.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            wv.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
            wv.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);
            wv.ScrollBarStyle = ScrollbarStyles.OutsideOverlay;
            wv.ScrollbarFadingEnabled = false;

            wv.LoadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html><body>---TESTING---</body></html>",
                    "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that's enough detail. Apologies if it's too much.

If anyone can help with this I would greatly appreciate it. I have searched the forum and cannot find an answer.

Comment: Because the app process is restarted and restored after being killed, the system will record the active task stack of the app before it is killed, and then resume directly to the top of the stack when the app is running. Check the `OnViewCreated` method in WebviewFragment, it may not execute after restarting app.

Comment: I added some Logging and found that the fragment events do all execute but it was happening milliseconds after the call from MainActivity to the OpenURL method. I've refactored my code and posted what I did to solve the issue. Thanks very much for getting me started down the path :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some debugging thanks to @y3z1 for pointing out where to start, it turns out the issue was that while the events in the fragment do execute they were not doing so in the correct order. My OpenURL method was being called prior to the OnCreateView method.

Thanks to this thread [Wait until fragment has been added to the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28457015/wait-until-fragment-has-been-added-to-the-ui) I then found the way to modify my code. Now the call to OpenURL is triggered from the events in the fragment, thus ensuring that it only happens after everything is initialized.

LoadProfile

```
private void LoadProfile()
{
    Fragment_Classes.WebViewFragment wvf = new Fragment_Classes.WebViewFragment();

    SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
        .Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, wvf)
        .Commit();

    SupportFragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();
}
```

WebViewFragment.OnResume

```
public override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();

    wv = view.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);

    ((MainActivity)this.Activity).OpenURL(this);
}
```

MainActivity.OpenURL

```
public void OpenURL(Fragment_Classes.WebViewFragment wvf)
{
    wvf.OpenURL(ep, true);
}
```

Comment: I certainly shall. It says I can't do so until tomorrow but I will asap. Thanks for your assistance once again :)